# JPA native query return class

Tags: java, jpa

In the JPA, I defined a native sql which will return String,

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "alert", 
query = " select distinct c.accountId from account c ", 
        resultClass = String.class)
```

the error message is

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.String
```

Any clues ? Thanks

Answer (score 18):

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "alertMapping", columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "accountId")})
})
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "alert", 
query = " select distinct c.accountId from account c ", 
        resultSetMapping = "alertMapping")
```

Usage:

```
EntityManager em = ...... / injected / etc
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createNamedQuery("alert", String.class);
List<String> accountIds = query.getResultList();
```

(unchecked syntax, but I hope the basic idea comes through)

For NamedNativeQueries you can only use resultClass when the result actually maps to an Entity. It's also possible to not specify a result mapping, in which case you'd get a `List` of Object[] back. Each element of the list would be one record, and you'd have to explicitly cast each Object to the type you wanted. Hm, the last part might only be available to NativeQueries and not Named - sorry unsure at the moment.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't find the bit about NamedNativeQueries only allowing "entity" result classes in the JPA spec. Have you got a section/page number? Thx

Comment: @esej "Hm, the last part might only be available to NativeQueries and not Named - sorry unsure at the moment." - I'm not sure what you meant by that, but I can confirm that treating the result list as Object[], like it's done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452586/sqlresultsetmapping-columns-as-and-entities/19790951#19790951) also works with a _@NamedNativeQuery_.

Answer (score 2):

Seems Hibernate only allows Entity result classes. Obviously not all JPA implementations have this restriction. [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/api.html), for example, allows that query to run fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include `resultClass` in query declaration

Comment: If I remove it, it will get another error. 
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported

Comment: I don't want to go this way. String will be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed hibernate version from 3.5.6 to 4.3.3. it is working fine.

```
<!--     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```