# jpa and native queries

Tags: jpa, nativequery

I faced with a strange thing with native queries:

If I'm trying to use named native query like the following

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "native_count_avg_guest_quizzes", resultClass = java.math.BigDecimal.class, query = "select avg(c) as r from ((select count(*) as c from user_quiz uq join user u on (uq.user_id = u.id) where u.status = 'temporary' group by u.id) as res)")
```

The application cannot run and I have

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: native_count_avg_guest_quizzes_
```

But the same query works fine if I do not use NamedNativeQuery and merely create a dynamic native query like the following:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                        "select avg(c) as r from ((select count(*) as c from user_quiz uq join user u on (uq.user_id = u.id) where u.status = 'temporary' group by u.id) as res)")
                        .getSingleResult()
```

Why? What I'm doing wrong with NamedNativeQuery? Thanks

**Update:**
Entity class is as following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_quiz")
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "native_count_avg_guest_quizzes", resultClass = java.math.BigDecimal.class, query = "select avg(c) as r from ((select count(*) as c from user_quiz uq join user u on (uq.user_id = u.id) where u.status = 'temporary' group by u.id) as res)")
})
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "list_clients_quizzes", query = "select uq from UserQuiz uq where uq.quiz.client.id = :clientId"),
    .......
})
public class UserQuiz extends Measurable {
.......
}
```

Comment: Did you mark the class with the query on it as either @Entity or @MappedSuperclass?

Comment: @user2800708 I did. The thing is the class had quite a few hql queries which worked without any troubles. The problem occurred only with this native query. I have updated the question with Entity class definition just in case. The idea is: the same exactly native query works just fine if it is created dynamically. I do not think the problem is with the entity definition. I think the problem is with the way NamedNativeQueries are processed

Answer (score 5):

`createNativeQuery` is used for native `SQL` query language that mean DB can understand and execute that query (Eg, `select * from some_table where id = '0001'`);

It may cause DB dependency. Now you are using `JPQL` language, that's why, use `createQuery()` or `createNameQuery()` with `@NameQuery` annotation sing.

Example :

**@NameQuery**

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllEmployee", query = "select e from Employee e")
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id int id;
    String name;
    // ...
}

Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllEmployee");
query.getResultList()
```

**Dynamic**

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e");
    query.getResultList()?
```

***Native**

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL");
query.getResultList()?
```

Comment: Not sure I understood you. I'm having troubles with a 'native' SQL query if I use it as a named query with `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation. The strange thing is that if I use exactly the same query right from the application code with `entityManager.createNativeQuery(...)` it works perfectly. Could you please explain how I can find a way to fix my problem based on your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Delete resultClass from @NamedNativeQuery.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9763489

> For NamedNativeQueries you can only use resultClass when the result actually maps to an Entity.